# how to run java class file in cmd line

Tags: java, compilation, command, javac

my 2 classes are like this:

```
package p;
class A{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    B b = new B("haha");
    b.run();
    //System.out.println("he");
  }
}
```

and

```
package b;
class B{
  String s;                             
  public B(String s){   
    this.s = s;
  }                             

  public void run(){
    System.out.println(s);              
  }                                     
}
```

I fail to compile these 2 files using `javac a.java b.java`, and the error is:

> a.java:4: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : class B 
>   location: class p.A
>       B b = new B("haha");
>       ^
>   a.java:4: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : class B
>   location: class p.A
>       B b = new B("haha");
>                 ^
>   2 errors

while after removing `package p;`,`javac a.java b.java` runs well.

So, how can I compile and run class A with the `package p;`?

======Edit=======
Thanks for all your reply,and finally I made my classes run by changing my files like this:

.
├── b
│   ├── B.class
│   └── B.java
└── p
    ├── A.class
    └── a.java

and a.java:

```
package p;

import b.B;

class A{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    B b = new B("haha");
    b.run();
    //System.out.println("he");
  }
}
```

B.java:

```
package b;
public class B{
  String s;
  public B(String s){
    this.s = s;
  }

  public void run(){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Things need to pay attention to :

- class B must be public
- should import B when trying to use it in class A

Comment: Did you import  package b in class A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will work.

```
//B.java

package b;

public class B{

  String s;

  public B(String s){

   this.s = s;

  }

  public void run(){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}


//A.java

package p;

import b.B;

class A{

  public static void main(String[] args){

B b = new B("haha");

b.run();

  }

}
```

Run "java p.A"

Answer (score 2):

add this line to your class A code:

```
import b.B;
```

It should be the very next line of the code following the package declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import type

```
import b.B;
```

and while executing the java class

goto dir a

and do

```
java a.A
```

---

**See**

- [packages & `import`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Either import other class by `import b.B`

or put both files in same folder(p) and remove `package b;` form class `B` it will get compiled.